# Seperate components from 'm/d/yyyy h:mm' formatted cell in Excel

Tags: excel, date, timestamp, excel-2007

I have cells in excel that contain a timestamp in the format of `m:d:yyyy h:mm` (single cell). Excel refers to the format as *custom*.  How can I extract the components?  Thanks.

e.g.

```
Timestamp
12/4/2012 0:32
...
```

would become

```
Timestamp month day year hour minute
12/4/2012 0:32 12 4 2012 0 32
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=MONTH(A1)
=DAY(A1)
=YEAR(A1)
=HOUR(A1)
=MINUTE(A1)
=SECOND(A1)
```

Assuming A1 contains the date.

Comment: removed my answer as yours is complete (@pnuts, stop hassling topics and being a know it all, if you want a perfect answer you can hire someone, for everything else there's StackOverflow)